# Set numpy array values through list comprehension

Tags: python, numpy, list-comprehension

I can change a set of values of a numpy matrix, passing the indices that I want to change in a list form, e.g. `matrix[[some first indices], [some second indices]] = 1`

I'm trying to do this but with only one list of indices and then for each element of that list as the first index and the whole list as the other index. Here the example:

```
import numpy as np

#Matrix
matrix = np.zeros((5,5))

# Indices
elements = [1,2,3]

# Way that works
for i in elements:
    matrix[i, elements] = 1
```

I would like to do this as a list comprehension, but I cannot figure out how, and, also, I'm not sure if it is a good practice. Something like `matrix[[(i,elements) for i in elements]] = 1`

Also thinking about to do it with itertools, for example `matrix[(itertools.permutation(elements, 2))] = 1`. But any of those approaches work, and I'm not sure why.

Comment: Are you just trying to set the whole matrix to 1? If so, then just `matrix += 1`

Comment: No, for every element on the list as a first index, and the entire list as a second.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that. Can you post your expected output?

Comment: A list comprehension should be used to create a new list.  While possible, it really shouldn't be used for side effects (e.g. modifying some other object).  It isn't a total replacement for a loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to access the 2d-matrix with row and colum arrays as index:

```
import numpy as np
matrix = np.zeros((5,5))
elements = [1,2,3]
matrix[np.c_[elements], elements] = 1
# array([[0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
#   [0., 1., 1., 1., 0.],
#   [0., 1., 1., 1., 0.],
#   [0., 1., 1., 1., 0.],
#   [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]])
```

Comment: Thanks, actually is a much better way than with list comprehension or itertools.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a `slice` from the first to the last element (+1) of `elements` (provided `elements` is ordered):

```
s = slice(elements[0], elements[-1]+1)

matrix[s, elements]= 1 
# [[0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
# [0. 1. 1. 1. 0.]
# [0. 1. 1. 1. 0.]
# [0. 1. 1. 1. 0.]
# [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]
```